# How to add share button to app for api's below 14?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

developer.android only shows a methed for api 14 an up, is there any other options that will allow a share button for api 8 and up? I tried searching for tutorials. Does anyone know of some good tutorials on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

The [ShareActionProvider training for the Action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ShareActionProvider) uses the [android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html) provided by the [AppCompat v7 support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) which, as the name suggests, works back to API 7.